# Using AnyClass in Swift when registering a TableView cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm having trouble with using AnyClass in Swift, when trying to register a TableView cell.

Example:

```
self.tableView.register(cellClass: AnyClass?, forCellReuseIdentifier: String)

self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self(NSObject), forCellReuseIdentifier: <String>)
```

When I pass in UITableViewCell (or its subclass), and invoke 'self' upon it, I'm expected to pass in an additional 'NSObject' parameter.

So far, what I've seen on the web is things like Class.self instead of Class.self(NSObject)

Please advise - Is this a new Swift API change?

Comment: Put just `UITableViewCell.self` without any parameters. It's a common language feature when you need to pass a particular type as a parameter.

Comment: It's not an API change. It's just a glitch of the autocompletion helper. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register nib name and it will load the class

```
 tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "mainTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier1)
```

OR

```
tableView.register(mainTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier1)
```

Comment: Thanks @Sh_Khan - as for the latter, I tried QuestionCell.self, but the IDE autocompletes it to 'QuestionCell.self(NSObject)' - I'm not sure what to pass in as the parameter for 'NSObject' --- i.e. it's not simply QuestionCell.self, but rather QuestionCell.self(NSObject)

*QuestionCell is a subclass of UITableViewCell

Comment: this autocomplete is not for that parameter if you typed say the name of the viewController.self it'll suggest that same parameter remove it and continue